# Get a Wordpress Users E-Mail by Username via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am currently building a Wordpress Login Form Plugin. Much like the [great GoSquared Login Form](https://www.gosquared.com/blog/login-screen-design) I want the Gravatar of the User currently logging in / resetting their password / registering to show up.

Since the Wordpress Login System works with Usernames I now want to find a way for my jQuery to send the Username to a PHP File which then returns the User's E-Mail Adress.

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Get Wordpress user email :**

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

So...

**use Ajax to get that email**

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

**Use**

`include('../../../../../wp-config.php');`

(Change your correct path)

use this whatever file you want to access your Wordpress db/funcs

**AND :** https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Noah, you may also find this useful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @CharliePrynn hahahaha :D

Comment: Sure. I know that much. But I don't know how I get the PHP File to get Access to the Wordpress Functions (This is properbly not very well formulated at all. Sorry.)

Comment: Thanks for your Help. Sorry if I was I wanted was kind of unclear.